# Why is this function pointer failing?

Tags: c++, c++builder

I have a group of functions and a function pointer declared as follows in my header file.

```
public:     // User declarations
void __fastcall TTopForm::Method1(void);
void __fastcall TTopForm::Method2(void);
void __fastcall TTopForm::Method3(void);
void __fastcall ( TTopForm::*Method )(void) ;
```

Then in my program, I do this

```
Method = Method1;
```

Which generates this error message: "Member function must be called or its address taken."
So of course I try this, but no luck.

```
Method = &Method1;
```

What am I doing wrong? I am a circuit designer, not a code expert, so please give some explicit code.

Thanks for the answers. I'll post what I did for anyone else that might be using C++ Builder. I am using a typedef per their help file. Omitting __fastcall in the typedef was one of my mistakes.

```
class TTopForm : public TForm
{
 typedef void (__fastcall TTopForm::* TMethod)(void);
 ...

 public:     // User declarations
 void __fastcall TTopForm::Method1(void);
 void __fastcall TTopForm::Method2(void);
 void __fastcall TTopForm::Method3(void);
 ...
```

Then in my code:

```
TMethod Method = &TTopForm::Method1;
(TopForm->*Method)();
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The correct syntax is `Method = &TTopForm::Method1;`.

Member functions of a class are a different beast from normal free functions. It might be better to think that they are completely unrelated.

You can only take the address using the syntax I show above. There is also a lot of other things you will need to learn to use them properly, for example, member functions always require an object to be called on.

Comment: Thanks, your syntax works, but now Method() gives a "call to a non function" error. Per your comment, I tried adding TObject *Sender to the function's argument list, but that didn't help.

Comment: I cannot see the code, but `Method` in your question is a *pointer* to a member function. You need to provide the object on which to call it upon. For example, assuming you had an object `t` of type `TTopForm`, you could call it like this: `(t.*Method)();`.

Answer (score 2):

Jesse answered the question according to what the C++ standard is expecting.  Since you are using C++Builder specifically, you can take advantage of its `__closure` compiler extension, which is much easier to use, and much more flexible, than standard C++ method pointers.  For example:

```
class TTopForm : public TForm
{
    typedef void __fastcall (__closure *TMethod)(void);
    ...

public:     // User declarations
    void __fastcall Method1(void);
    void __fastcall Method2(void);
    void __fastcall Method3(void);
    ...
};
```

```
TMethod Method = &Method1;
Method(); // calls this->Method1()
```

What makes `__closure` flexible is that it is not limited to any particular class.  It holds a reference to the object pointer, so it doesn't need to know the original class type at all.  For example, the following is also valid:

```
typedef void __fastcall (__closure *TMethod)(void);

class TTopForm : public TForm
{
public:     // User declarations
    void __fastcall Method1(void);
    ...
};

class TBottomForm : public TForm
{
public:     // User declarations
    void __fastcall Method1(void);
    ...
};
```

```
TTopForm *TopForm = ...;
TBottomForm *BottomForm = ...;
TMethod Method;

Method = &(TopForm->Method1);
Method(); // calls TopForm->Method1()

Method = &(BottomForm->Method1);
Method(); // now calls BottomForm->Method1(), using the same TMethod variable!
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to take it's address like this:

```
Method = &TTopForm::Method1;
```

Answer (score -1):

I feel

```
Method = Method1;
```

should have been:

```
Method = ObjectOfClass.Method1
```

I am not sure however.